# What is and what is an example of the function that Partial Derivative basis vectors act on in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, general-relativity, tangent-spaces

When defining the tangent space there is some function $f$ that is defined on the manifold in order for the vector (as it is a linear map) to act on. I'm confused as to what this function does and what an example would be.

Say we have some manifold $M$ and a family of curves, parameterised by $\lambda$, going through a point $p$ on the manifold.

$\phi : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$

$\phi :\lambda \mapsto \phi(\lambda) $.

$\phi(0) = p$.

We have some chart map $x$ that takes a local region into $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we name the image of the curves in the chart $x^\mu(\lambda)$. $x : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

$(x\circ\phi) : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

$(x\circ\phi): \lambda\mapsto \phi(\lambda) \mapsto x^\mu(\lambda)$

Then we define some functions on the manifold. $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f \in C^\infty(M)$. Then we evaluate the function $f$ on the curve on the manifold, $f(\phi(\lambda))$.

The tangent vector acting on $f$ to the curve at the point $p$ is: $$V_\phi(f) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}}f(\phi(\lambda))$$

Then...

$$\phi(\lambda) = x^{-1}\circ x^\mu(\lambda)$$

$$f(\phi(\lambda)) = f(x^{-1}\circ x^\mu(\lambda)) = (f\circ x^{-1}) \circ (x^\mu(\lambda))$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}}(f\circ x^{-1}) \circ (x^\mu(\lambda)) = \frac{\partial(f\circ x^{-1})}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}}$$ $$(f\circ x^{-1}) = f(x^\mu)$$ $$V_\phi(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}} = (\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}) f $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial\lambda}\Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} = V^\mu\partial_\mu$$

What is an example of something that the basis $\partial_\mu$ would act on. Also arent we getting tangent vectors to the curve from just the parameter derivative, why do we need this derivative of $f$, what is $f$ actually meant to represent, just some random scalar field? I think my understanding is very flawed.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a tangent vector is. The modern definition of a tangent vector being the same as a directional derivative at a point is just a trick to make the definition of the tangent bundle coordinate independent. I recommend you read the very nice chapter about tangent bundles in spivak s concise  introduction to differential geometry volume 1. It has a lot of pictures and three different descriptions of the tangent bundle.